# ASP/VBScript - Int() vs CInt()

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

What is the difference in ASP/VBScript between `Int()` and `CInt()`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

- [Int()](http://www.w3schools.com/Vbscript/func_int.asp)

> The Int function returns the integer part of a specified number.

- [CInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_cint.asp)

> The CInt function converts an expression to type Integer.

And the best answer comes from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9(VS.85).aspx)

> CInt differs from the Fix and Int functions, which truncate, rather than round, the fractional part of a number. When the fractional part is exactly 0.5, the CInt function always rounds it to the nearest even number. For example, 0.5 rounds to 0, and 1.5 rounds to 2.

Comment: god, i wonder how many people are aware they are rounding only the nearest even number. Was rewriting a function from vba into python, thanks for this.

Comment: Gosh this is old, BUT additionally, Int returns the a value of the same type it received, so it might well be a double with fractional part all being zeros, while CInt always returns an integer value. Imho, this is the worst pitfall which breaks your neck once you build on Int returning a non-float.

Comment: My IDE lies, my prev comment is false, Int returns what it gets, type-wise, and so does Fix. CInt fails with VBScript for large values, CLng covers higher values, it returns a long integer.

Answer (score 18):

And, the most important difference (IME, at least)....is that CInt [overflows at 32,767](http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art18651.asp).

Comment: Many thanks for the reminder that int is a signed 16 BIT integer!

Comment: Later versions and environments for VBScript have larger points of overflow.  E.g. VBScript 15.8 and above are good up to +/- 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 5):

The usual answer for this issue is to manually force a re-rounding. This problem is as old as FORTRAN.

Instead of

```
a = int(40.91 * 100)
```

Use

```
b = 40.91 * 100
a = int(b + 0.5)
```

Very old trick, still useful in Excel spreadsheets from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another difference:

Script:

```
wscript.echo 40.91 * 100
wscript.echo Int(40.91 * 100)
wscript.echo CInt(40.91 * 100)
```

result:

```
4091
4090   (????)
4091
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Floating point rounding. The actual value of "40.91" in the code is extremely close to but just less than the theoretical decimal value. CInt rounds to nearest, Int truncates.