# ASP Fix/Int functions not behaving as expected

Tags: vbscript, integer, asp-classic, rounding

While debugging I found this weird thing in a custom RoundMid() function :

```
    test = 148.325 * 100 + 0.5
    Response.Write test ' Returns 14833
    Response.Write Fix(test) ' Returns 14832 ???????

    test = 14832.5 + 0.5
    Response.Write test ' Returns 14833
    Response.Write Fix(test) ' Returns 14833
```

Same problem with Int() instead of Fix().
Any idea what can I do to obtain 14833 on the second line ?
Thank you.

Comment: Not weird, just [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/6s7zy3d1(v=vs.84)). Try `test = (148.325 * 100) + 0.5`.

Comment: @user692942 Thank you for your suggestion but I already tried that and same result. The test variable as a value of 14833 before the Fix() in both cases (at least according to the Response.Write).

Comment: Use `CInt(test)` or `CLng(test)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP/VBScript - Int() vs CInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675/asp-vbscript-int-vs-cint)

Comment: The duplicate link doesn't quite cover it, since your expression is expected to result in a whole number. I assume the float value is internally something like 14832.99999999999, so Int and Fix return 14832 because they truncate.

Comment: You'll probably find the explanation [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors).

Comment: @LesFerch Thanks for your responses. CInt() and CLng() don't work for what I want to do with values ending in 5. I'm trying to fix the native Round() function to always round up if the decimals end in 5, regardless of whether it's an even or odd number, and with a setting for the number of decimals similar to the Round() function. However, it's more complex than I anticipated by simply adding 5 to the last decimal.

Comment: Therefore, I'm leaning towards a function that adds 0.1 to the last decimal if there are more decimals than desired. For example, if I want to round 148.325 with 2 decimals, I'll add 0.1 and call `Round(148.3251, 2)` to obtain 148.33, as desired, instead of 148.32 obtained with `Round(148.325, 2)`.

Comment: This could help: [Cannot round up a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443249/cannot-round-up-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

In the second calculation, both the numbers 0.5 and 14832.5 can be represented as powers of 2.
They can be stored exactly in binary without rounding errors.

0.5 = 2<sup>-1</sup>
14832.5 = 2<sup>13</sup> + 2<sup>12</sup> + 2<sup>11</sup> + 2<sup>8</sup> + 2<sup>7</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>-1</sup>

The sum 14832.5 + 0.5 can also be represented exactly:
14833 = 2<sup>13</sup> + 2<sup>12</sup> + 2<sup>11</sup> + 2<sup>8</sup> + 2<sup>7</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>

In the first calculation 100 can be represented exactly in binary:
100 = 2<sup>6</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup>
But the number 148.325 cannot be represented exactly. The binary representation of this number is:
10010100.010 1001 1001 1001 ... with the 1001 repeating.

So the binary representation will always be slightly less than 148.325 no matter the number of digits used.

When the decimal part of the calculation 148.325 * 100 + 0.5 is truncated, the result is 14832.