# Comparing numeric values not as expected (VBScript)

Tags: vbscript, numbers, precision, comparison-operators

I stumbled upon a strange behavior of VBScript when comparing numerical values. I expect it's a rounding issue but I can't figure out how I can improve the code to behave as expected.

```
Dim angle

angle = 3.55*180.0/3.55
MsgBox CheckValue(angle)        ' returns True

angle = 3.56*180.0/3.56
MsgBox CheckValue(angle)        ' returns False (unexpected!)

Function CheckValue(input)
    Dim check
    check = False
    If input = 180.0 Then check = True
    CheckValue = check
End Function
```

Comment: You can use `Round(input,2)` or `angle = Round(3.55*180.0/3.55,2)`, at least from a quick google it said it also exists in VBScript. In VBA it just showed twice True so I'm not really sure why VBScript is acting up about it.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't strange, it is a limitation of the way that floating point arithmetic works as not all decimal numbers (especially ones with fractions) can be stored accurately in binary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP Fix/Int functions not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787181)